# Why react-native routers use state instead of props?

Tags: react-native, redux, reactjs-flux

There is [an official react-native example](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/Navigator/NavigationBarSample.js#L92) regarding routing which uses props instead of state.

However all other router component libraries use state instead of props. Especially, the libraries that have prepared for `Flux` and `Redux` usages.

What is the main idea of state usage in router components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why they use navigator=this.props.navigator in this example is that this is a child component, where a parent component is passing down its navigator to the child through props. You generally do not pass down state directly into a child component, you pass down a prop that could be used in "getInitialState".

https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html

Here we see that this is simply the syntax used to pass a prop from parent to child. We want to pass the navigator between different components so that the app is consistent, they are all using the same navigator to navigate between different pages.

Just a warning though, when passing props as state to a child component, note it should be clear that it's only for [initialization](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html).

Comment: But when considering the navigation, [examples][1] create new route and continue to the new route (to a child in this case). And can be turned from new page to two page ago. Using breadcrumbNavSample and navigationBarSample example this situation can be seen. Did you mean that roaming from `friends\work` to `settings\theme` (jumping)? If the UI allows a roam in this way Facebook example doesn't work. [1]:https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/UIExplorer/Navigator